# How to convert string to date format in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I want to parse the following string

> Wed Nov 18 20:22:45 +0000 2015

to date and time format in Tableau. Any idea how to use calculated fields? Tableau using the calculated field and DATEPARSE function?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dateparse('EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss Z yyyy', [YourString])
```

refer to http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime for a full list of parameters to specify your date.

Comment: Excellent, Alexander!!  it worked perfectly. Great help,Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work for me ("Unknown function Dateparse called") - is there something I should do to make Dateparse available?

Comment: It depends on the datasource you use. Some of them do not support date parse. You would need to create an extract to make use of it.