# Datetime Tableau Calculation - Convert String to Datetype

Tags: datetime, tableau-api, type-conversion

I am attempting to write a case statement in tableau. I am casing the date field where I want to control for a specific date range.

```
CASE [Date] WHEN [Date] >= DATETIME('1/1/17') and [Date] < DATETIME('1/11/17')        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

However, I am getting a error -
"Expected type data, found boolean. Compare in case must be date type.

I got the same error using:
     DATEPARSE('mm dd yyyy','1/1/17')

I understand my error. However, I can't seem to identify the function which convert my string into a date.

This post didn't help either.
[How to convert string to date format in Tableau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33791689/how-to-convert-string-to-date-format-in-tableau)

Anyone know?

Comment: Assuming [date] is a properly recognised date, why not just use a filter? If you want to use literal dates you need to format them correctly. In your dateparse function the format string **clearly** doesn't match the date literal. That is why it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works

```
sum(if year([Date]) == 2017  and MONTH([Date]) == 1 then [profit] END)
```

I'd still like to see the case solution if anyone can figure it out.